# Python typing: define type of the classvar based on another var

Tags: python, mypy, typing

Is it possible to define type of the python class field based on another field?
Something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar


@dataclass
class A:
  a: str


@dataclass
class B(A):
  b: str


@dataclass
class UseA:
   field_cls: ClassVar[type] = A
   field: A  # <-- here should be something other, not just "A"


class UseB(UseA):
  field_cls = B

  def print_b(self) -> None:
    print(self.field.b) # Here mypy says that "A has no attribute b"
```

If I'll run **mypy --strict** on this code I'll get the `error: "A" has no attribute "b"`.

I need to define the type of "field" dynamically by another field "field_cls" so type checkers like mypy and my IDE (vscode) have to understand the right type of the **UseB.field**

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? Can you say why a simple generic `Use[T]` won't do?

Comment: You need to use a type-variable.

Comment: @joel can you can provide the full example?

Comment: I don't want to make an answer because this is probably a duplicate, but sth like
`T = TypeVar("T"); class Use[T]:   field_class: ClassVar[type[T]]   field: T`, though the `field_class` may be redundant here